# Laravel Eloqeunt CAST() table column with postgres generating error

Tags: postgresql, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 with Postgres. I have an integer column where I need to put a condition with like `%%`. I have a postal_code columns where integers values are saved. Now I need to get all rows those have `12` in that.  But we cannot do that with integer datatype so I am casting it as text while doing query but I am getting error.

Here is my code

```
$query->where("cast(postal_code as TEXT)", "LIKE", "%".$request['postal_code']. "%");
```

And it is generating error

```
"cast(postal_code" as "text)"
```

Please see the unwanted `"` being put in query. This is the query output error. Is this the error Or there is some thing other went wrong and how can I fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think casting a field on where in laravel doesn't seem to be worked.Execute a raw query using whereRaw function.

```
$query->WhereRaw("cast(postal_code as TEXT) ILIKE '%?%',[$request['postal_code']]");
```